# control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, stdvector

I wrote a code fragment such that:

```
int gnrt(vector <int> vect, int n)
{
    std::vector <int> :: iterator it;
    it = find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), n);
    if(it!=vect.end()) gnrt(vect, n+1);
    else return n;
}
```

where I'm trying to find a number n that is not similar to any elements inside the vector. But it keeps showing the warning:

```
In function 'int gnrt(std::vector<int>, int)':
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Anyone please explain what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if(it!=vect.end()) gnrt(vect, n+1);
    else return n;
```

Your if case is not returning a value.

You probably want to do this:

```
if (it!=vect.end()) 
     return gnrt(vect, n+1);
else 
     return n;
```

I don't know what compiler you are using, but typically the line where the error or warning is generated will be shown to help you find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

your function is expected to return an `int`

```
int gnrt(vector <int> vect, int n)
```

your code however doesn't return that

```
if(it!=vect.end()) gnrt(vect, n+1);
    else return n;
```

a little bit of re arrangement should indicate that if the `if condition` evaluates to `true` vitz, `it!=vect.end()` you return nothing and compiler is not happy about that

```
if(it!=vect.end()) 
    gnrt(vect, n+1); // this one 
 else 
     return n;
```

---

Your function actually has couple of exit points.

1. the normal exit point that is the end of function surrounded by { }
2. the `return` statement

because this function expects some `int` value to be returned from all those exit points any uncovered exit point is a potential warning

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought about the base case here.